# Issue using .net 2.0 Logger Class

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have been trying to use [the class located here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.logger%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) . But I have not been able to get this to work.  I obviously do not understand something correctly, But I am curious how to get that example Logger class to work. 
**My research** has sent me towards using MSBuild but the use of MSBuild correctly is still baffeling me.  Any pointers would be helpful. I have built the logger class into a .dll,and referenced it in the project as well, but that is where my research seemed to run dry with helpful information.

**My goal** currently is just to get the above noted logger class working so I can use my own logger class.

Comment: what errors are you getting, or what exact issues are you running into?

Comment: You're trying to add custom logging during the build? Or are you trying to add logging to your application?

Comment: The issue that I am running into is that I cant seem to get any logging to happen.  I created a dummy project that just calls a dummy method hoping to be able to get something to happen but it doesn't seem to do anything for logging.  I have a strong feeling that I am missing something, but I guess I dont know enough about logging to be able to pin point the issue.

Comment: Mike, Im trying to be able to run an application and have it log data, that way I can easily debug the application.  I may be trying to make it harder on myself by not using a third party package, but this is my current mindset to just write my own logger.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is specifically for logging MSBuild events.  If you want a generic logger that has nothing to do with MSBuild look at some of these alternatives:

- [MS Enterprise Library - Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)
- [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)
- [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (designed for logging ASP.NET errors, but *can* be used to log other events)
- [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)

Comment: Okay If I wanted to create my own generic logger, I had seen some people online using System.diagnostic.tracesource, is that the path that I would want to go? I am trying to steer clear of third party packages

Comment: That could be one method.  It doesn't support database logging, which others do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of using a library to do the work. In the tutorial [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/swisscoder/archive/2012/05/13/c-tutorial-for-log4net-again.aspx) for `log4net` it's a simple seven step process to start using a fully functional and scalable logging library. I'm going to inline pieces of the tutorial just in case the link ever dies.

First you build a very simple configuration section in your `App.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log-file.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

For your needs you pretty much just need to change the `value` of the first `param` named `File` as it's already setup to append to a text file.

Next you'll need to run the configuration in some startup method, like `Application_Start` or the `main` method of your program.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Finally, just use it by plugging in a couple of lines:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bar));
... (rest of class)
... (somewhere in a method) ... log.Debug("this is the first log message");
```